# How to add year, month, day from two datetime in C# Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

I got two datetime from two textboxes and calculate the year, month, day and concate the values like << 1 Year 3 month 3 days >> and save into Experience(column name).
Suppose, in this column there are also some value such as

```
                      >> 1 Year 3 month 2 days
                      >> 2 Year 10 month 10 days
```

now I want to add those column values and show the value in a label << 4 Year 1 month 12 days >>
how can I do this in C# Asp.Net? Can anyone help to do this please...

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, did you want to calculate from each textbox the diff from today's date and finally add the diffs and display on label?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to convert a DateTime to `1 Year 3 month 2 days`. Also, it is unclear whether you need to make this calculation on the client-side (JavaScript) or the server-side during a post/get request (C#). Please provide more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Adding years of 2 dates makes absolutely no sense... 2016 + 2015 = what? - which explains why you can't find a way to solve it. Using proper type (TimeSpan for example) would make this question completely unnecessary.

Comment: will you please read my explanation? I said I got two date from 2 textboxes and calculate year, month, day from those date and concate the value like 1 year 2 month 3 days which i got and save into database column. such as more value save into the column . Now I want to read those value from database and sum those value and show on lable. @Alexei

Comment: No. Imagine, Experience is a database table column name. In this column here is some value like
         >> 1 year 3 month 2 days
         >> 2 year 10 month 15 days
Now I want to read the column values from databse and sum these value and show total result. Result will be 4 year 1 month 17 days.  got me @Tarkil

Comment: I calculate from server side and save the value into database. Now I want to read those values from database and get the sum of those values. @NightOwl888

Comment: Actually, you can't. A year can be 365 or 366 days, a month 28-31 days, so your result will be "4 years 1 month _some_ days". So, initially, store the _timespan_ between the two textboxes and you're done - as these can be summed right away.

Comment: As I read it, you just want the time span in between two dates. You can subtract the first DateTime from the second one to get a TimeSpan object. Then you will have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

OK so following your comment I understand based on the "experience" column that you want to store the length of time someone does something.
the best way to actually do this while taking care of things like 31 days in a month, leap year etc is to store the actual dates (start, end).
than, you calculate the diff between the dates:

```
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);
System.TimeSpan diff2 = date4.Subtract(date3);
```

and than you add the 2 timespans:

```
System.TimeSpan added = diff1.Add(diff2);
```

In order to get the correct data out of it you must add to a date, so the computer can calculate the special year, days in month etc.
so for instance adding the added to today's date:

```
System.DateTime today = System.DateTime.Now;
System.DateTime answer = today.Add(added);
```

this is a better way to achieve what you wanted.
if you only need a rough estimate do 3 cols: years, months and days and add them up with division so:
if added days \ 30 > 0 => add 1 month etc.

**EDIT**

Since you want to parse strings, and not change the structure, if you are:
sure that the format is constant so each time: "x years y months z days" including the spaces, do this:

```
string[] parts = str.Split(' '); // split by spaces
// now the numbers are in fields 0,2,4
int years = 0;
int.TryParse(parts[0],out years);
int months = 0;
int.TryParse(parts[2],out months);
int days = 0;
int.TryParse(parts[4],out days);
```

this is for 1 of the spans. do it for the 2nd and add the parts (days to days etc).

after that do the add and something like:

```
if (addedDays > 30) 
{
  addedMonths++;
  addedDays = addedDays - 30;
}
```

etc.

Comment: suppose, "1 year 3 month 2 days" is string. Now tell me from this string how can i get 1, 3 and 2 ? @ tarkil

Comment: this will be messy. why not change the structure of the db? parsing string is not a good idea when you can do it better...

Comment: No, I can't. that's structure what i needed. will you give me any solution? @tarkil

Comment: Perfect point about the fact one can't add two "intervals" expressed as y/m/d instead of just days - there is really no way to answer even 15d+15d with single result (like 1 month 2 days). Side note: OP got the code in copy-paste ready answer already (and did not accepted even that solution...) - so I'd not expect any more attention from OP.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you.

```
        List<string> experiences = new List<string>() {"1 Year 3 month 2 days", "2 Year 10 month 10 days"}; //don't know how you populate it. Use your method here to populate experiences array.

        int years = 0;
        int months = 0;
        int days = 0;
        foreach (var experience in experiences)
        {
            years += experience.Contains(" Year ")
                ? int.Parse(experience.Split(new[] {" Year "}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].Replace(" ",""))
                : 0;
            months += experience.Contains(" Year ") && experience.Contains(" month ")
              ? int.Parse(experience.Split(new[] { " Year " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Substring(0,2))
              : 0;
             days += experience.Contains(" month ") && experience.Contains("days")
            ? int.Parse(experience.Split(new[] { " month " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Substring(0, 2))
            : 0;
        }

        if (days > 30)
        {
            int monthsInDays = days/30;
            months += monthsInDays;
            days = days%30;
        }
        if (months > 12)
        {
            int yearsInMonths = months/12;
            years += yearsInMonths;
            months = months%12;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total experience is {0} Years {1} Months {2} Days", years, months, days);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, Thank you so much :)
It works ...@Kosala W